# Drupal Views Issue

Tags: php, drupal

So we have a drupal site and it is an article intense site.

We have a bunch of articles that are categorized.

On the home page there is a hero slider and 3 thumbnails boxes below it that contain articles as well.

The default logic is that the home slider is pulling the most recent articles posted. The issue is that one of the thumbnails below it pulls the most recent article as well.

How do we make it so that the article that appears in the home hero slider never matches what is in any of the 3 thumbnails below it?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Under PAGER section of the View, you will find an Offset setting, you could use this to skip some nodes from the second view so it skips the nodes already shown by the first view, of course, in order for this to work, both views need to be using the same sorting logic.

If the criteria for sorting is more complicated or the nodes are manually selected for each section, then you have to use another taxonomy term to "mark" those nodes intended to appear in the Hero section from the nodes somewhere else.